# Flutter/Dart: speech to text (offline)

Tags: flutter, dart, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, speech-to-text

Is there any package that I can use to create an app that can process speech to text?

It should include the following features:

offline speech to text

Answer (score 0):

I think the best choice would be https://pub.dev/packages/speech_to_text.
It is frequently updated and you can make it listen continuously if needed.

Another choice could be https://pub.dev/packages/speech_recognition, but according to its docs it could have some limitations.

> On iOS, by default the plugin is configured for French, English, Russian, Spanish, Italian. On Android, without additional installations, it will probably works only with the default device locale.

Comment: Can i use offline speech to text in this package https://pub.dev/packages/speech_to_text .

Comment: Yes, it's continuous and you can use it offline